# Visual Studio 2010 cannot detach from process

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wrapper

I have a c++ Solution that consists of 3 Projects.The 1 of them is a wrapper (c#).Everything was fine until now that when i try to Compile (after i successfully build the project) the VS2010 crashes and is shows that : cannot detach from one or more processes.

Here is an image : https://imageshack.com/i/eyr82nExp

When i try to Run using ctr + F5 everything goes fine.

Thank you...

P.S Even with ctr + F5 sometimes when i close my project the same message is shown.

Comment: Can you post the exact message error or a screenshot of the msn box ?

Comment: *Even with ctr + F5* that makes no sense: if the debugger isn't started how can it crash? Are you sure it's not some leftover from a previous session?

Comment: @stijn Probably yes is a leftover...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  finally did it. Something went wrong with Visual Studio's Personal Preferences.

So, i had to delete them all and then everything was nice..

The steps i did are described [here](http://ugek010.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/visual-studio-windows-disappear-after-debugging/)